# Rails 4 confirm a new user's email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, password-recovery, email-confirmation

I have gone through the Rails 4 tutorial at http://railstutorial.org/chapters and finished **most** of the exercises.  Several of the suggested extensions to the project are on the top of my list for the next step in creating my application.  These are the email confirmation upon signup feature and the remember password feature.  I've noticed several gems would help me with this, but when I watched several of the Railscasts and read a few tutorials, they didn't really apply to my situation or involved a complicated gem to handle it all (Devise).  Also, it was always assumed in tutorial for Devise that I was starting from scratch, which is not the case as I have said.  Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction for accomplishing these two features with the limited experience that I have that is considered safe and simple to implement?

Also, it is worth mentioning that I ultimately chose state_machine as a useful gem to utilize for this functionality as well as future functionality.  If anyone has thoughts on that one way or the other, I would love to hear.  Right now, two states exist in my User model: inactive and active.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.  Thanks!

### Edit:

I'm choosing to implement the signup registration link in the email I send users who signup for my site.  I have created a UserMailer class that successfully sends an email to the user upon signup.  I'm contemplating where to put the update to the email_token attribute of my users table:

- ### Option 1:

/app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
 ...
 def create
   redirect_to_root_if_signed_in

   @user = User.new(user_params)

   if @user.save
     sign_in @user
+    @user.update_attribute(email_token: User.encrypt(User.new_token))
     UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver
     flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
     redirect_to @user
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end
 ...
```

- ### Option 2:

/app/models/user.rb

```
   before_create :create_email_token

 ...

   private

     def create_email_token
       self.email_token = User.encrypt(User.new_token)
     end
```

### Also:

1. What would I name the controller responsible for responding to the
   click of the url in the email by the user?  How would one format the
   url so the controller will respond with the toggling the activation
   state I have?  The state is an integer value with names `:active`
   and `:inactive` using the `state_machine` gem.
2. What is the RESTful way of specifying the route?  How do I generate the url in the user_mailer.rb?  Should it be a get or put in my routes.rb?

Comment: "Remember password" are you talking about "remember me"? As for the email confirmation on sign up is that really needed? That step is great place to lose users. That process doesn't convert very well. I would recommend the easiest route. Not doing it.

Comment: Remember password is when you forget it and the application puts you through a process that allows you to recover it or reset it with a temporary one.  Does "remember me" do that?  And as for email confirmation, I would certainly like to have the opportunity to email my users, and if the only check I do is a regex one for format on the email, there is no way for me to assume that their email is a real one.  Also, without confirming it, why store it at all?  What do you mean the process doesn't convert very well.  The biggest sites I know use this process and don't lose many users, right?

Comment: That's not "remember password", it's "forgot password".

Comment: You are right.  But another main concern here is the email confirmation.  Any thoughts there?

Comment: What is the process to get this question taken off hold?  I could really use some help here, and having the question remain on hold after I provided more information to specify my issue more explicitly is difficult for my quest in finding a solution.

Comment: @JakeSmith FYI your asking TWO questions in one SO thread, you probably should have split each question into their own thread.  As for the "remember me" functionality I would suggest watching Ryan Bate's railscast episode 274, http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a high level overview of a solution.

On the user model you will need a boolean column with a default state of false. You will also need a string column to store token. A token would be a random string obtained by something like `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64`.

Then you should need a controller which will accept the token as a parameter and then find the user by its token and change the value of the aforementioned boolean field.

Next you would need a mailer that would send a email to the user with the url to active the account.

If you have any additional questions let me know.

Comment: thank you.  This is pretty synonymous with my assumptions with some of the holes filled in.  Through my efforts of learning web development, I've noticed that there are a lot of security concerns that are pointed out to me that I would have never thought of on my own.  Can you think of any security issues that I should be aware of with this implementation?

Comment: Also, I will implement this and get back to you as soon as I can, and mark your answer as THE answer when I get it working :)  Thank you so much

Comment: I'm thinking that I want to set the email_token attribute of my users table in the users_controller.rb on the subsequent line of the `UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver`.  Would you agree that that would be the best place to call the `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64`?  Or should I put it in a before_create in the user.rb file?  I will update my question with the code in question...

Comment: I would call `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64` in the model For example `@user.set_token` should be called in the controller. Then send mailer in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it with the token field. When they login and put in the right token (proving they have put in the right email), the token column in their user database entry gets set to null, which means they are validated.